# How to show the contents of a component in another component?

Tags: angular

I want to show the contents of a component in another component.
This is my `menu.component.html` that I want to show in `app.component.html`:

```
<div class="Tree">
<tree-root [nodes]="nodes">
<ng-template #treeNodeTemplate let-node let-index="index">
<a><span>{{ node.data.description }}</span></a>
</ng-template>
</tree-root>
</div>
```

I'm using `angular-tree-component` to show data in tree form.

This is my `app.component.html` where I'm using the `<menu>` selector of the menu component to show the menu:

```
<menu [path]="path"></menu>
```

The problem is that I only get the first element of the tree instead of getting the data in tree form.

Comment: Are you sure `nodes` is correctly initialized?

Comment: @gsamaras yes, I am sure

Comment: @gsamaras for more info, look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46785288/cant-show-the-contents-of-a-component-in-another-component

Answer (score 0):

Why not you use Event emitters to transfer data between components

```
//Home component.ts
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';  
constructor(public events: Events) {
     directioChange(user) {
            this.events.publish('directiochanged', 'true');
     }
} 


//AngularTreeComponent
constructor(public events: Events) { 
       events.subscribe('directiochanged', (direction) => { 
             //Do your Tree view display Action in this receiver
       });
 }
```

Comment: The `angular-tree-component` is an npm package that takes some data and displays it in tree form and I don't know how it does it and I'm using it precisely because I didn't want to implement this functionality by myself.